# Send post request using axios with parameters as JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs, api, post, request

I have a problem wit sending JSON object as a parameter to my post API

I get 404

```
const params = {"id": 1, "title" : "x"}

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '......',
    data: params
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log('success')
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error();
    });
```

Comment: Please add the specific problem to your question with any error messages that you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Api resource that you want to access is not there causing `404` Not Found Error. Go through your api resources and see if your requested resource is present or not. Some servers are very specific regarding `/`. e.g. `/users` may not match `/users/` and vice versa.

Comment: Awesome,  Have a great day :)